# Change value of one cell based on partial contents of another plus Fuzzy Lookup video?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using Excel version 2010. Perhaps there is a better and easier way (that actually works) in 2010. I hope someone can help.

Simple description:
If I have a group of words in Column A that may (or might not) include the word 'Agreement' . If the word 'Agreement' is in the sentence in Col A, then I want Column B, same row, to say 'Confidentiality Agreement'. Otherwise, if the word 'Agreement' is missing, it should say 'Supporting Documents'.

```
Example:
Col A =============> Col B
ABC Agreement =====> Confidentiality Agreement
ABC Tests =========> Supporting Documents
etc.
```

Since the word 'Agreement' will not be the only word in the cell in Column A (if it is there at all), I have a 2-step process so far:

Step 1: Select all of Col A. Use 'Conditional Formatting' "wizard" (on Home toolbar, not VBA) and choose 'Highlight Cell rules' and choose 'Text that contains' and enter the word 'Agreement'. It will change the cell in Col A to RED and will not touch Col B. This part works.

Now, on to Col B:
Then, using the advice from this link, I try to get Column B to notice the color of the associated cell in Col A. See last solution on this page:
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-form...ther-cell.html

Issues:

1. the VBA code references the Interior.ColorIndex which "appears" to change the background color, but really is some other sort of overlay color that only LOOKS like the background color. What is the true name of the object which changes a cell's apparent color when using the above wizard (the Conditional Formatting wizard)? It is NOT 'Interior.ColorIndex' .
2. The VBA code only runs when I type any small formula into any random cell and press enter. The 'Volatile' part of the code seems to make that happen. Is that Volatile stuff really needed?

Finally, if anyone has a reference to a good online video about how to get Fuzzy Lookup (an add-on) to work, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to get the formatting? If you want to use formulae, you can use an `IF` associated with `SEARCH`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("agreement",A1)),"Confidentiality Agreement","Supporting Documents")
```

Put that in cell B1 if the first cell you want to test is in A1.

---

If you want to use colours, why not simply use a filter, filter on all the coloured cells and fill all the rows of column B which are visible with `Confidentiality Agreement` and otherwise (filter on cells without any colour) with `Supporting Documents`?